# How to call properties/methods of a javascript object from server side object

Tags: javascript, java, c#, jquery, angularjs

I normally get a js object from restful resource Web Api 2 using C#, jQuery 2.x, Chrome as a browser like this

**C#**

```
public class Employee
{
   private int id;
   private string firstName;
   private string lastName;

   public int ID
   {
      get{ return this.id; }
      set{ this.id = value; }
   }

   public string FirstName
   {
      get{ return this.firstName; }
      set{ this.firstName = value; }
   }

   public string LastName
   {
      get{ return this.lastName; }
      set{ this.lastName = value; }
   }

   public string FullName
   {
      get{ return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName; }
   }   
}
```

I have a controller like this

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{

   [HttpGet]
   public Employee GetEmployee(int id)
   {
      return EmployeeService.Instance.GetEmployee(id);
   }

}
```

Then in my js I call the resource like this

```
function getEmployee(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "localhost:8080/Employee/" + id,
        success: bindEmployee
    });
}

function bindEmployee(employee){
   alert(employee.FullName);
}
```

**Java**

Now I want to do same thing in Java using Jersey 2.23, Java json 1.0, Tomcat 8. So my class Employee

```
public class Employee{
  private int ID;
  private string firstName;
  private string lastName;

  //regular getter and setter methods

  public string getFullName(){
     return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
}
```

This is my restful resource

```
@Path("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getEmployee(@PathParam("id") long id) throws JSONException{
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setId(id);
        employee.setFirstName("john");
        employee.setLastName("smith");
        return Response.status(200).entity(employee).build();
    }
}
```

I call the restful resource with $http object from angularjs like this

```
return $http({
 method : 'GET',
 url : 'localhost:8080/employee/1',
}).then(onSuccess, onError);

function onSuccess(response){
   return response.data;
}

function onError(response){
//
}
```

The response data is my employee but I can only see the private members, but I cannot call the getFullName method. Is not in a JSON string, it is a Javascript object.

Is there a workaround to call the getFullName in javascript? I want to avoid a client side concatenation like this firstName + " "+ lastName.

This is the output from developer tools in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: Question is very unclear. Where is what language being used (client/server/browser)? Is actual JSON data transmitted always the same regardless of language, and what does it look like?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Btw, why the vote to close. The user could have the kindness to explain why?

Comment: Did you read the [Jersey document about JSON](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json) that specifies how you can control the way a POJO is mapped to JSON? It has the answer you're looking for, like most documentation does.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the Java object is being serialized into JSON to be sent over the wire to the browser but the fullName field is not being serialized with the object. While the javascript won't have access to the method getFullName, you can serialize arbitrary fields such as including a fullName field on Java side. I can't tell what serialization lib you are using with Jersey, but if you are using Jackson, you can simply annotate the method as a JSON property:

```
@JsonProperty("fullName")   
public string getFullName() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;   
}
```

You can also use tools like Moesif and Fiddler to see what is the payload going over the wire.

Comment: Please clearly mention your relationship with Moesif in your answer; otherwise, it could be considered spam. Please see **[the help center here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)** for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In c# your GetFullName is a Property.
In Java it's a function.

JSON only serializes Properties. If you want your Java Object to serialize the FullName you would either have to convert it into a Property or Annotate it.

Comment: Do you have some code to show ? Can you do it thanks to [edit] ?

Comment: @Derrick posted code above. That could do the trick.
The only problem with that is, there is no setter. But since you won't set the Property Server Side its should be fine.